# Period of oscilation of thin plate in the form of circular section

Tags: moments, experimental-physics, inertia-matrix

*A thin plate of mass m in the form of  a circular section of radius R and angle alpha is hanged to oscillate back and fort from a horizontal support. Find its period of oscillation.*

I am confused how to find moment of inertia in relation to the axis around it oscillates. [image]

Comment: I can answer your question, but first you should provide more information on what you already tried and perhaps identify the spot that confuses you.